# Linux Shell Script to execute another shell script using variables defined in multiple text files

Tags: php, linux, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to write a Linux Shell Script to do some automation on my server. I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 by the way.

Basically, the process is as follows:

A. I create multiple text files using PHP in a directory (/home/mydir). These text files are stubs of a shell script, and they contain only variable definitions. Here is a sample of what might be in one of the files.

```
username="myusername1"
password="mypassword1"
othersettings="othersettings1"
```

B. I have a setup shell script that references the above variables. Below is a part of what may be in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir /home/newdir/$username
```

I'm trying to write an activation shell script that will find out how many of these files are in the /home/mydir and then execute the setup shell script for each one of the files in the directory. So, for example, if I have 5 files with 5 different username, password, etc. the setup script will be run 5 times using the variables in each of the text files to complete the tasks defined in this script.

I'd appreciate some assistance on how to write such a script. The way my mind is working is that I should use maybe `ls -1 /home/mydir | grep .txt` to get all txt files, then extract them to an array, and then iterate and execute the script, but I'm not a shell scripting expert so I need some assistance with the syntax. If shell scripting was PHP, it wouldn't have been a problem for me, but alas, it is not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know, you can use PHP at the command line. I believe the Ubuntu package is is `php5-cli`. Then you could write PHP scripts.

Comment: @Derobert: Yes I know, but I plan to run this script using CRON.

Comment: Nothing keeps you from running PHP scripts from cron. Shell script is in no way special. Put the `#!/usr/bin/php` line up top, chmod +x it, and it'll run like any other program.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, I'm sure it'll be much easier too. I'm using PHP-FPM, which I compiled from source. Do I have to install php-cli regardless?!

Comment: Well, I just assumed that you were using the packaged PHP. If you're using a self-compiled version, you just need to compile it for command-line support. You may have already done so; see if you have a 'php' or 'php5' command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this in shell is something like this:

```
for f in /home/mydir/*.txt; do
    . "$f" # source settings file
    mkdir "/home/newdir/$username"
done
```

But as I mentioned in my comment, you could just write your script in PHP.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
...
?>
```

**EDIT**

Your code works, I just edited it for calling a shell script within a shell script, which is what I really wanted to do. So the below code works too.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in /home/dir/*.txt
do
   . "$f"
   . /path/to/setup-shell-script #referenced in B of the original question
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `.` or `source` command is for in shell scripts; it will read the contents of the argument (file) and execute them.  Beware of people forcing your script to use a file you did not intend them to use.  Note that C shell includes the `source` command (Bourne shell only supported `.`); Bash provides both.

```
. /home/mydir/mystery_settings_file
mkdir /home/newdir/$username
```

Note that if you write:

```
. mystery_settings_file
```

the shell will search for it using $PATH, but the file only has to be readable (it does not need to be executable).  This can be quite useful.